# How to use netstat to show what process is listening on a port

Tags: networking, macos, netstat

I'm on an OS X Mountain Lion laptop and have a couple of Vagrant boxes on it. I'm trying to figure out which process is listening on port 8080. My variations produce like a hundred lines but none with specific port number. I'm assuming something like:

```
netstat -XXX | grep 8080
```

Comment: Is this in a home setting or professional environment?

Comment: well, recreating an server enviro locally. if you want to move to different site, that's fine. Different versions of netstat support different arguments.

Comment: Okay then sir, everything seems in order here, please carry on and  have a nice day.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Unfortunately on OSX you're stuck with the BSD `netstat` which will not show you the process ID that is attached to a given port. What you have to do instead is use `lsof`. The syntax you'll need to use is:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

This will print out gobs of information, most of which you don't care about, but the fields are well labeled. For example, check out this example output.

```
lsof -i :53237
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
GoogleTal 927 guest   29u  IPv4 0x2c3f7f95244855c3      0t0  TCP localhost:53237 (LISTEN)
```

This tells me that port 53237 is in use by process ID 927. When reading the COMMAND field keep in mind that this output is truncated, in reality the full name of the binary is GoogleTalkPlugin.

Comment: thx, this gets me a lot closer, it's going to a fairly generic `VBoxHeadl` - is there any way to see which VirtualBox instance (have two right now) or am I asking way too much (propably the latter). thx

Comment: @timpone: I don't know enough about VirtualBox to help you down that path. You can check the process command line to see if it's listed there, or use `lsof -p PID` and browse the list of open files until you find it.

Comment: cool, thx for help

Answer (score 8):

This is what I like to use when looking for a listening port's PID.
For Linux use: `netstat -tunlp`

- n network
- l listening ports
- p process
- t tcp
- u udp

Additional information can be found  in the man pages.

Comment: `-p` does not list the arguments to the program. How do I see this?

Comment: OP asked about OSX. -p is not an option on OSX version of netstat.

Comment: `-p` on OSX is `port`. I hate the developers decisions to make different arguments for OSX and Linux...

Comment: This command doesn't work the same on macOs, which the question is about

Answer (score 6):

I was in the process of modifying `netstat` on OS X to provide this feature and stumbled upon the fact that `-v` will give you the pid associated with a socket.

Comment: The `-v` increases the verbosity level and it is documented. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html

Comment: sorry, I meant the fact that it prints the PID is not documented, not that the option exist.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the following two lines work best to show which apps have listening ports open, and tunnel, lsof is fully cross-platform:

```
netstat -Watn | grep LISTEN
lsof -Pnl +M -i -cmd | grep LISTEN
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out specific port use below netstat command

```
  netstat -an | grep ':8080'
```

Comment: OP asked about getting the process.  This does not show the process id.

Answer (score 0):

From man netstat

-p, --program
       Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.

I usually just do this:
netstat -antup | grep 8080

Comment: hmm... this sounds like what I'd like but this is giving me different options on OS X for -p `-p protocol Show statistics about protocol, which is either a well-known name`

Comment: @timpone: The `-p` to display the PID is a GNU netstat command whereas OSX uses BSD netstat.

Comment: `-p` does not list the arguments to the program. How do I see this?

Comment: OP asked about OSX. -p is not an option on OSX version of netstat.

Comment: `-p` on OSX is `port`. I hate the developers decisions to make different arguments for OSX and Linux...

Comment: Darwin (macOs) has a different meaning for -p, it's the protocol to display.

Answer (score 0):

The below command shows the connection:

```
netstat -antop | grep :8080
```

For viewing the complete flow in realtime you could use `watch`:

```
watch -d -t -n 1 'lsof -n -i :8080'
```

Answer (score 0):

On `Ubuntu 18.04` and

```
netstat --version
net-tools 2.10-alpha

sudo netstat -ltnpv | grep 53
```

is the correct netstat command flag. 6th column is showing you the process.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5335          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21219/unbound       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8953          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21219/unbound       
tcp        0      0 192.168.5.165:7135      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2538/python3        
tcp        0      0 192.168.5.165:7138      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2539/python3        
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      17715/docker-proxy
```